Automating a regular data import into Sendgrid
I'm a marketer not developer, and would like understand 1) how easy is it to create an automatic import add/update file into Sendgrid 2) does this require an API or can it be done without?
I currently upload data manually for one off sends but want to create an automated welcome series which add new contacts daily into the segment but not sure how
